# Jump-next/prev icon for Pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have question about jump-next/prev icons for Pagination element. In `Pagination.d.ts` file we can see `itemRender` prop with some types (including jump-next/prev). But calls with parameters jump-next/prev never come to method `itemRender`.

```
export interface PaginationProps 
{
total?: number;
defaultCurrent?: number;
disabled?: boolean;
current?: number;
defaultPageSize?: number;
pageSize?: number;
onChange?: (page: number, pageSize?: number) => void;
hideOnSinglePage?: boolean;
showSizeChanger?: boolean;
pageSizeOptions?: string[];
onShowSizeChange?: (current: number, size: number) => void;
showQuickJumper?: boolean | {
    goButton?: React.ReactNode;
};
showTotal?: (total: number, range: [number, number]) => React.ReactNode;
size?: string;
simple?: boolean;
style?: React.CSSProperties;
locale?: Object;
className?: string;
prefixCls?: string;
selectPrefixCls?: string;
itemRender?: (page: number, type: 'page' | 'prev' | 'next' | 'jump-prev' | 'jump-next', originalElement: React.ReactElement<HTMLElement>) => React.ReactNode;
role?: string;
showLessItems?: boolean;    }
```

How I can show jump icons with types jump-next/prev on Pagination element?

Comment: Please may you move the text in the image into the question _as text_?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Did it

Comment: May you also show the methods?